# Join two table by dates and populate the missing data when one table has missing dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server, I have a two tables (`tbl1` and `tbl2`) as shown below. `tbl2` contains a list of all dates. In `tbl1`, some of the dates are missing.

**tbl1**

```
name    nameid  count   date
-----------------------------------------------
apple     1      77     2019-07-29 00:00:00.000
orange    2     129     2019-07-29 00:00:00.000
apple     1     399     2019-08-05 00:00:00.000
orange    2      27     2019-08-05 00:00:00.000
apple     1     122     2019-08-12 00:00:00.000
orange    2       5     2019-08-19 00:00:00.000
```

**tbl2**

```
    timeid     date
5   2019-07-29 00:00:00.000
4   2019-08-05 00:00:00.000
3   2019-08-12 00:00:00.000
2   2019-08-19 00:00:00.000
1   2019-08-26 00:00:00.000
```

What I need is the table below. I need to join the two table, populate the name and nameid for the missing dates, and set those counts as 0.

```
date                    name nameid count   timeid
---------------------------------------------------
2019-07-29 00:00:00.000 apple   1     77    5
2019-07-29 00:00:00.000 orange  2     129   5
2019-08-05 00:00:00.000 apple   1     399   4
2019-08-05 00:00:00.000 orange  2     27    4
2019-08-12 00:00:00.000 apple   1     122   3
2019-08-12 00:00:00.000 orange  2     0     3
2019-08-19 00:00:00.000 apple   1     0     2
2019-08-19 00:00:00.000 orange  2     5     2
2019-08-26 00:00:00.000 apple   1     0     1
2019-08-26 00:00:00.000 orange  2     0     1
```

I did the following:

```
SELECT t1.date, name, nameid, count, timeid 
FROM tbl2 t1
LEFT JOIN tbl1 t2 ON t1.date = t2.date
```

and got this output:

```
date                    name     nameid    count    timeid
----------------------------------------------------------
2019-07-29 00:00:00.000 apple       1        77      5
2019-07-29 00:00:00.000 orange      2       129      5
2019-08-05 00:00:00.000 apple       1       399      4
2019-08-05 00:00:00.000 orange      2        27      4
2019-08-12 00:00:00.000 apple       1       122      3
2019-08-19 00:00:00.000 orange      2         5      2
2019-08-26 00:00:00.000 NULL        NULL    NULL     1
```

It does not seem to be right. Does anyone know how I can generate the desired joined table?

Below is the code to generate `tbl1` and `tbl2`

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tbl1

CREATE TABLE tbl1 
(
    name VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    nameid INT NOT NULL,
    count INT NOT NULL,
    date DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO tbl1(name, nameid, count, date)
VALUES ('apple', 1, 77, '2019-07-29'),
        ('orange', 2, 129, '2019-07-29'),
        ('apple', 1, 399, '2019-08-05'),
         ('orange', 2, 27, '2019-08-05'),
         ('apple', 1, 122, '2019-08-12'),
         ('orange', 2, 5, '2019-08-19');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tbl2

CREATE TABLE tbl2 
(
    timeid INT NOT NULL,
    date DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO tbl2(timeid, date)
VALUES (5,'2019-07-29'),
        (4,'2019-08-05'),
         (3,'2019-08-12'),
         (2,'2019-08-19'),
         (1,'2019-08-26');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve your desired result, you need to cross join the distinct name values from `tbl1` with the dates from `tbl2` and then `LEFT JOIN` that to `tbl1` again, using `COALESCE` to replace `NULL` values of `count` with 0:

```
SELECT t2.date, n.name, n.nameid, COALESCE(t1.count, 0) AS count, t2.timeid
FROM tbl2 t2
CROSS APPLY (SELECT DISTINCT name, nameid FROM tbl1) n
LEFT JOIN tbl1 t1 ON t1.date = t2.date AND t1.name = n.name
ORDER BY t2.date, n.name
```

Output:

```
date                        name    nameid  count   timeid
2019-07-29 00:00:00.000     apple   1       77      5
2019-07-29 00:00:00.000     orange  2       129     5
2019-08-05 00:00:00.000     apple   1       399     4
2019-08-05 00:00:00.000     orange  2       27      4
2019-08-12 00:00:00.000     apple   1       122     3
2019-08-12 00:00:00.000     orange  2       0       3
2019-08-19 00:00:00.000     apple   1       0       2
2019-08-19 00:00:00.000     orange  2       5       2
2019-08-26 00:00:00.000     apple   1       0       1
2019-08-26 00:00:00.000     orange  2       0       1
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a49ef75ecbf786398680feb73894de0b)